# docker-proxy getting accept4: bad file descriptor

Tags: docker, proxy

I am trying to add a port forwarding to docker container using docker-proxy but experiencing this error below,

Here are the details,

- A container with IP 172.17.0.2 is already running with --net=none. We are providing our own network and not using docker0 network.
- Now we want to expose some ports of container to host, so thought of trying docker-proxy.
- we executed the below command,

  ```
  $ docker-proxy -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8000 -host-ip 0.0.0.0   -host-port 8000 -proto tcp
   and we are getting,
   2017/03/16 10:02:30 Stopping proxy on tcp/[::]:8001 for tcp/172.17.0.2:8001 (accept tcp [::]:8001: accept4: bad file descriptor)
  ```

Docker version: Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any other way of doing this but stopping the container, removing it, then running it again starting from a Dockerfile or simply with docker run by adding -p 8000:8000.
Docker doesn't seem to let you tinker with docker-proxy directly, you have to use the standard commands.

You could also manually expose the port to outside access by directly changing the iptables, i.e. DOCKER chain in the NAT table and the DOCKER chain in filter.
For instance:

```
iptables -t nat -A DOCKER ! -i your_bridge0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8000
```

And:

```
iptables -A DOCKER ! -i your_bridge0 -o your_bridge0 -d 172.17.0.2 -p tcp --m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Of course then you'd have to make sure that the rules are going to stick, which is quite a different problem altogether. Docker doesn't seem to care much about who manages iptables (ufw, firewalld etc.).

This will work, even if docker proxy isn't running at all. docker-proxy binds to the host's ports, which means you control the traffic on the INPUT chain in the filter table (so the host itself).
I still haven't figured out why docker was built this way, but by default, if you expose a container (using -p) and then you delete the DNAT rule, it will still work, because the request is going to hit the INPUT chain directly. Which is mind-boggling, but never mind.

Answer (score 0):

the docker-proxy binary cannot be called outside dockerd directly, If you want call it outside anyway, try look the moby source code [the key code is here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/8bb58153e75b4310f3ae9ec6d03924aa286fbf20/libnetwork/portmapper/mapper.go#L170)

there is an example

```
    package example

    import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "net"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
        "runtime"
        "strconv"
        "syscall"
        "time"

        "github.com/ishidawataru/sctp"
    )

    const userlandProxyCommandName = "docker-proxy"

    func newProxyCommand(proto string, hostIP net.IP, hostPort int, containerIP net.IP, containerPort int, proxyPath string) (userlandProxy, error) {
        path := proxyPath
        if proxyPath == "" {
            cmd, err := exec.LookPath(userlandProxyCommandName)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            path = cmd
        }

        args := []string{
            path,
            "-proto", proto,
            "-host-ip", hostIP.String(),
            "-host-port", strconv.Itoa(hostPort),
            "-container-ip", containerIP.String(),
            "-container-port", strconv.Itoa(containerPort),
        }

        return &proxyCommand{
            cmd: &exec.Cmd{
                Path: path,
                Args: args,
                SysProcAttr: &syscall.SysProcAttr{
                    Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGTERM, // send a sigterm to the proxy if the creating thread in the daemon process dies (https://go.dev/issue/27505)
                },
            },
            wait: make(chan error, 1),
        }, nil
    }

    // proxyCommand wraps an exec.Cmd to run the userland TCP and UDP
    // proxies as separate processes.
    type proxyCommand struct {
        cmd  *exec.Cmd
        wait chan error
    }

    func (p *proxyCommand) Start() error {
        r, w, err := os.Pipe()
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("proxy unable to open os.Pipe %s", err)
        }
        defer r.Close()
        p.cmd.ExtraFiles = []*os.File{w}

        // As p.cmd.SysProcAttr.Pdeathsig is set, the signal will be sent to the
        // process when the OS thread on which p.cmd.Start() was executed dies.
        // If the thread is allowed to be released back into the goroutine
        // thread pool, the thread could get terminated at any time if a
        // goroutine gets scheduled onto it which calls runtime.LockOSThread()
        // and exits without a matching number of runtime.UnlockOSThread()
        // calls. Ensure that the thread from which Start() is called stays
        // alive until the proxy or the daemon process exits to prevent the
        // proxy from getting terminated early. See https://go.dev/issue/27505
        // for more details.
        started := make(chan error)
        go func() {
            runtime.LockOSThread()
            defer runtime.UnlockOSThread()
            err := p.cmd.Start()
            started <- err
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            p.wait <- p.cmd.Wait()
        }()
        if err := <-started; err != nil {
            return err
        }
        w.Close()

        errchan := make(chan error, 1)
        go func() {
            buf := make([]byte, 2)
            r.Read(buf)

            if string(buf) != "0\n" {
                errStr, err := io.ReadAll(r)
                if err != nil {
                    errchan <- fmt.Errorf("Error reading exit status from userland proxy: %v", err)
                    return
                }

                errchan <- fmt.Errorf("Error starting userland proxy: %s", errStr)
                return
            }
            errchan <- nil
        }()

        select {
        case err := <-errchan:
            return err
        case <-time.After(16 * time.Second):
            return fmt.Errorf("Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy")
        }
    }

    func (p *proxyCommand) Stop() error {
        if p.cmd.Process != nil {
            if err := p.cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return <-p.wait
        }
        return nil
    }

    type userlandProxy interface {
        Start() error
        Stop() error
    }

    // ipVersion refers to IP version - v4 or v6
    type ipVersion string

    const (
        // IPv4 is version 4
        ipv4 ipVersion = "4"
        // IPv4 is version 6
        ipv6 ipVersion = "6"
    )

    // dummyProxy just listen on some port, it is needed to prevent accidental
    // port allocations on bound port, because without userland proxy we using
    // iptables rules and not net.Listen
    type dummyProxy struct {
        listener  io.Closer
        addr      net.Addr
        ipVersion ipVersion
    }

    func NewDummyProxy(proto string, hostIP net.IP, hostPort int) (userlandProxy, error) {
        // detect version of hostIP to bind only to correct version
        version := ipv4
        if hostIP.To4() == nil {
            version = ipv6
        }
        switch proto {
        case "tcp":
            addr := &net.TCPAddr{IP: hostIP, Port: hostPort}
            return &dummyProxy{addr: addr, ipVersion: version}, nil
        case "udp":
            addr := &net.UDPAddr{IP: hostIP, Port: hostPort}
            return &dummyProxy{addr: addr, ipVersion: version}, nil
        case "sctp":
            addr := &sctp.SCTPAddr{IPAddrs: []net.IPAddr{{IP: hostIP}}, Port: hostPort}
            return &dummyProxy{addr: addr, ipVersion: version}, nil
        default:
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unknown addr type: %s", proto)
        }
    }

    func (p *dummyProxy) Start() error {
        switch addr := p.addr.(type) {
        case *net.TCPAddr:
            l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp"+string(p.ipVersion), addr)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            p.listener = l
        case *net.UDPAddr:
            l, err := net.ListenUDP("udp"+string(p.ipVersion), addr)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            p.listener = l
        case *sctp.SCTPAddr:
            l, err := sctp.ListenSCTP("sctp"+string(p.ipVersion), addr)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            p.listener = l
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("Unknown addr type: %T", p.addr)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func (p *dummyProxy) Stop() error {
        if p.listener != nil {
            return p.listener.Close()
        }
        return nil
    }
    func Proxy(hostip string, hostport int, containerip string, containerport int) error {
        // userlandProxy, err := NewDummyProxy("tcp", net.ParseIP("0.0.0.0"), 8888)
        userlandProxy, err := newProxyCommand("tcp", net.ParseIP(hostip), hostport, net.ParseIP(containerip), containerport, "/usr/bin/docker-proxy")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        cleanup := func() error {
            // need to undo the iptables rules before we return
            userlandProxy.Stop()
            // pm.DeleteForwardingTableEntry(m.proto, hostIP, allocatedHostPort, containerIP.String(), containerPort)
            // if err := pm.Allocator.ReleasePort(hostIP, m.proto, allocatedHostPort); err != nil {
            //  return err
            // }

            return nil
        }

        if err := userlandProxy.Start(); err != nil {
            if err := cleanup(); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("Error during port allocation cleanup: %v", err)
            }
            return err
        }
        return nil
    }
```

and call it in main package like:

```
func main() {
// ne(proto, hostIP, allocatedHostPort, sctpAddr.IPAddrs[0].IP, sctpAddr.Port, pm.proxyPath)

if err := example.Proxy("0.0.0.0", 8080, "172.17.0.10", 8080); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("err.Error(): %v\n", err.Error())
}
time.Sleep(time.Second * 500)
```

}